# Underline first letter in CheckBox

Tags: c#, forms

I have a c# form and when I put `CheckBox` and set text to Text&Input. 'I' should be underlined but it is underlined only when I hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think this is a windows behaviour rather than your application.

Answer (score 1):

Put an `&` character in front of the character that should be the shortcut. Like

```
chk.Label = "&Text";
```

As for the actual underlining, Windows has an option to hide underlining by default until you press the ALT key.

This link may be useful in turning it on, but then this is not a programming question but a UI question.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/where-is-hide-underlined-letters-for-keyboard/17e253e4-3802-46d1-99d1-6563574dabe8

Note that this also applies to Windows 8.1.

Comment: I did i wrote Text&Input. But 'I' should be underlined all the time not just when I hold ALT

Comment: @SavaFilipovic Yes, you did - I misread your question. I updated the answer with a link. You should self-close your question, though - this is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it's about using Windows.

Comment: @xxbbcc he can't close his own question because he doesn't have enough rep.

Comment: @mmking I flagged the question for mods to move it to superuser.com.